# swedish character corrupted when running from command line

Tags: java, apache

I have a simple java program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.LogOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("c:/echo.bat");
/*CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("cmd.exe ");
commandLine.addArgument("/c");
commandLine.addArgument(" echo Båt"); */

DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
try {

LogOutputStream output = new LogOutputStream() {
@Override
protected void processLine(String line, int level) {
System.out.println(line);
}
};
PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(output);
executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);

executor.setExitValue(0);

DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);

} catch (ExecuteException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

If I run this from the batch file which contains "echo Båt", the output shows correctly:

C:>echo Båt
Båt

But if I run it with "cmd /c echo Båt", the output is corrupted:

B†t

Anyone has any idea? Thanks.

I did more testing by using ‘-Dfile.encoding=’ setting after seeing comments from Jouni Aro(Thanks!). And here are the results:

1)  No setting (use system default):

Charset is: windows-1252

C:>echo Båt
Båt

Charset is: windows-1252

B†t

2)  ‘-Dfile.encoding=UTF8’:

Charset is: UTF-8

C:>echo Bï¿½t
Bï¿½t

Charset is: UTF-8

Bï¿½t

3)  ‘-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1’:

Charset is: ISO-8859-1

C:>echo Båt
Båt

Charset is: ISO-8859-1

B†t

so looks the charset is not helping here?

Comment: The difference is in the code pages. In the batch file the charset is the same that cmd.exe will use, but when you compose the command in Java, it is using a charset that does not match the default charset of cmd.exe.

I am not sure, which charset the CommandLine object will use for the string, though, or if you can convert your string for the correct charset for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try in java `"B\u00e5t"`. The problem probably is that the encoding of the editor (the java source) is a different one than used for the javac compiler.

If you edit in "UTF-8" then it must be

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 ...
```

Comment: 'B\u00e5t' result is same: 

Charset is: UTF-8
Bï¿½t

Charset is: ISO-8859-1
B†t

Charset is: windows-1252
B†t

Comment: I am convinced that you should try `Cp850` this is the DOS code page with `å`. Used by the Windows command line.

Comment: Charset is: IBM850
BankL†net

Comment: And Cp850 stands for code page 850. Maybewikipedia can tell more.

Comment: In wikipedia: Systems largely replaced code page 850 with, firstly, Windows-1252 (often mislabeled as ISO-8859-1)...

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This file created at 2016年1月11日.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2002-2016 Honey, Inc. All rights reserved.
 */
package com.honey.proxy.helper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog;
import org.apache.commons.exec.Executor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.honey.proxy.exception.CmdRunException;

/**
 * <code>{@link AbstractCommonExecs}</code>
 *
 * TODO : document me
 *
 * @author Honwhy
 */
public abstract class AbstractCommonExecs {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractCommonExecs.class);
    private static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private String encoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING;

    private String bin;
    private List<String> arguments;
    public AbstractCommonExecs(String bin, List<String> arguments) {
        this.bin = bin;
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    public ExecResult exec() throws CmdRunException{
        ExecResult er = new ExecResult();
        try {
            Executor executor = getExecutor();
            CommandLine cmdLine = getCommandLine();
            log.info("Executing script {}",cmdLine.toString());
            if(supportWatchdog()) {
                executor.setWatchdog(getWatchdog());
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(outputStream);
            //ByteArrayOutputStream errorStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream,errorStream);
            executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
            int ret = executor.execute(cmdLine);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pis, getEncoding()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            pis.close();
            String stdout = sb.toString();
            //String stdout = outputStream.toString(getEncoding());
            String stderr = errorStream.toString(getEncoding());
            er.setStderr(stderr);
            log.info("output from script {} is {}", this.bin, stdout);
            log.info("error output from script {} is {}", this.bin, stderr);
            log.info("exit code from script {} is {}", this.bin, ret);
            er.setStdout(stdout);
            er.setExitCode(ret);
            return er;
        } catch (ExecuteException e) {
            throw new CmdRunException("", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CmdRunException("", e);
        }

    }

    public Executor getExecutor() {
        Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setWorkingDirectory(new File(this.bin).getParentFile());
        return executor;
    }
    public CommandLine getCommandLine() {
        String fullCommand = bin + join(arguments);
        return CommandLine.parse(fullCommand);
    }
    protected String join(List<String> arguments) {
        if(arguments == null || arguments.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String arg : arguments) {
            sb.append(" ").append(arg);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return the encoding
     */
    public String getEncoding() {
        return encoding;
    }

    /**
     * @param encoding the encoding to set
     */
    public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public abstract boolean supportWatchdog();
    public abstract ExecuteWatchdog getWatchdog();
}

//=====================
// Test class
/**
 * This file created at 2016年1月12日.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2002-2016 Honey, Inc. All rights reserved.
 */
package com.honey.command;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog;

import com.honey.proxy.helper.AbstractCommonExecs;
import com.honey.proxy.helper.ExecResult;

/**
 * <code>{@link GbkCommonExecs}</code>
 *
 * windows开发环境测试
 *
 * @author Honwhy
 */
public class GbkCommonExecs extends AbstractCommonExecs{

    /**
     * @param bin
     * @param arguments
     */
    public GbkCommonExecs(String bin, List<String> arguments) {
        super(bin, arguments);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.bingosoft.proxy.helper.AbstractCommonExecs#supportWatchdog()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supportWatchdog() {
        // TODO implement AbstractCommonExecs.supportWatchdog
        return false;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.bingosoft.proxy.helper.AbstractCommonExecs#getWatchdog()
     */
    @Override
    public ExecuteWatchdog getWatchdog() {
        // TODO implement AbstractCommonExecs.getWatchdog
        return null;
    }

    public String getEncoding() {
        return "GBK";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bin = "ping";
        String arg1 = "127.0.0.1";
        List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();
        arguments.add(arg1);
        AbstractCommonExecs executable = new GbkCommonExecs(bin, arguments);
        ExecResult er = executable.exec();
        System.out.println(er.getExitCode());
        System.out.println(er.getStdout());
        System.out.println(er.getStderr());
    }

}
```